# how to fix self create module not working

Tags: python-3.x, module

My self made module is not returning an expected result( I want to input ABC and get back 123, But it is not doing that)

I am doing this to learn how to do this and so I can make my code look cleaner.(I am trying to make a very complicated message encoder and this is my first step)

```
    def counter(key):
    length = len(key)
    counting = 0
    word = []
    try:
        while length != counting:
            if key[counting] == 'A' or 'a' :
                word += '1'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'B' or 'b' :
                word += '2'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'C' or 'c' :
                word += '3'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'D' or 'd' :
                word += '4'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'E' or 'e' :
                word += '5'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'F' or 'f' :
                word += '6'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'G' or 'g' :
                word += '7'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'H' or 'h' :
                word += '8'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'I' or 'i' :
                word += '9'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'J' or 'j' :
                word += '10'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'K' or 'k' :
                word += '11'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'L' or 'l' :
                word += '12'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'M' or 'm' :
                word += '13'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'N' or 'n' :
                word += '14'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'O' or 'o' :
                word += '15'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'P' or 'p' :
                word += '16'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'Q' or 'q' :
                word += '17'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'R' or 'r' :
                word += '18'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'S' or 's' :
                word += '19'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'T' or 't' :
                word += '20'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'U' or 'u' :
                word += '21'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'V' or 'v' :
                word += '22'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'W' or 'w' :
                word += '23'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'X' or 'x' :
                word += '24'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'Y' or 'y' :
                word += '25'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == 'Z' or 'z' :
                word += '26'
                counting += 1
            if key[counting] == ' ' :
                word += '#'
                counting += 1
    finally:
        return word
```

I want this module to let you input any phrase and convert the letters to numbers(A = 1, B =2, C = 3, etc.) and return the phrase back translated in numbers. 
( I am not importing wrong)

To test I imputed 'Hello I am Sam' and I got back
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '4'] This is obviously not right, so what is the problem.
This is the way my import looks

```
import random
from h import counter
key = "Hello I am Sam"
keyascii = counter(key)
print(key)
print(keyascii)
```

Comment: `key[counting] == 'A' or 'a'` this doesn't work as you expect - it is `(key[counting] == 'A') or 'a'`. It has to be `key[counting] == 'A' or key[counting] == 'a'` or `key[counting] in ('A', 'a')`. Or use `lower()`/`upper()` - `key[counting].lower() == 'a'`

Comment: instead of `while length != counting:` you could use `for char in key:` and then you compare `if char.lower() == 'a':` And you don't need `length` and `counting`.

Comment: I will apply this and see how it goes

Comment: if something doesn't work then use `print()` to see what values you have in variables in different places and which part of code is executed (`print("I'm in while")` - it is called "print debugging". Or learn how to use real debuger ;)

Comment: I used key[counting] in ('', ''): and it worked

Comment: you could use dictionary `data = {"A": "1", "B":"2", ...}` and search in dictionary `if char in data: word += data[char]`. Code will be much shorter.

Comment: You don't even need a dictionary, check my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

I am using [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) to get the integer representation, and subtracting it with 64 to get the integer equivalent you specified in your code.
I am converting each character into uppercase, since you want both A and a to be 1, B and b to be 2 and so on. I am appending a whitespace character as it is

```
def counter(s):

    result = ''
    for c in s:
        if c != ' ':
            result += str(ord(c.upper())-64)
        else:
            result += ' '
    return result

print(counter('ABC'))
print(counter('Hello I am Sam'))
#123
#85121215 9 113 19113
```